# google.protobuf import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

I am trying to install tensorflow so that I can install keras on top of it.
I am encountering: 
    `ImportError: No module named google.protobuf`

I am working with virtual environments. I have used pip to install protobuf. I encounter this when I use the command `pip install protobuf`

```
`Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf)`
```

According to documentation, it should have worked.

Here is my view when I try to install tensorflow:

```
`>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/swaghccc/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/swaghccc/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/swaghccc/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf`
```

I have not been able to find the correct answer to this problem. I have read I must "simply install protobuf" but unfortunately that is not helping.

Please help.

Comment: I guess this will help you [Import google.protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326951/google-protobuf-import-error)

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing.
`ImportError: No module named google.protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

Your protobuf is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and your active environment is in `/Users/swaghccc/.virtualenvs/keras_tf`.

Activate your virtual env `keras_tf`. Make sure you are in that environment. You can do so by executing `which python`. That should return a path that includes `keras_tf` in it. Then, do `pip freeze`. See if `protobuf` is installed. If not, install it while you are in that environment. Then, try importing `tensorflow` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. `pip list` or `pip show` can find the package of protobuf, but when I imported tensorflow in the Python shell it raised the error of no module. Finally, I solved this problem by reinstalling protobuf by `sudo pip install protobuf` or in root. Hope this helps.